# Pandas list of tuples to MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
    id    t_l
0   100   [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
1   151   [('x', 4), ('y', 3)]
```

I need to return a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
    id    f    g
0   100  'a'   1
1        'b'   2
2   151  'x'   4
3        'y'   3
```

What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: 
@ALollz makes a good point about speed of `np.concatenate` vs. `chain.from_iterable(df.t_l)`. I `%timeit` and it is true. Therefore, I added solution using `from_iterable(df.t_l)`

```
from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(df.t_l), index=np.repeat(df.id, df.t_l.str.len()), \
                                          columns=['f', 'g']).reset_index()
```

**Original**:

I would construct a new `df` using `np.concatenate` for data and `np.repeat` for index. Finally, `reset_index` to put `id` back to column

```
pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.t_l), index=np.repeat(df.id, df.t_l.str.len()), \
                                              columns=['f', 'g']).reset_index()

Out[596]:
    id  f  g
0  100  a  1
1  100  b  2
2  151  x  4
3  151  y  3
```

Comment: `np.concatenate` will slow down considerably for a larger DataFrame. Can use `chain.from_iterable(df.t_l)` from itertools

Comment: @ALollz: hah, it is very interesting. Is it because numpy have to convert tuples to array before concat?. +1

Comment: I like itertools

Answer (score 1):

```
df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([list(i) for i in list(x.t_l)]), axis=1).stack().apply(pd.Series).rename({0:'f',1:'g'}, axis=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

OR.. removing the `pd.Series` approach for efficiency

```
pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([list(i) for i in list(x.t_l)]), axis=1).stack()).rename({0:'f',1:'g'}, axis=1).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
     f  g
id       
100  a  1
100  b  2
151  x  4
151  y  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply()` AND `pd.multiindex` :-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [ [100, [('a', 1), ('b', 2)] ] , [151,[('x', 4), ('y', 3)]] 
], columns=['id', 't_1'] )


inside, outside, value = [], [], []
c = 0
def get_outside(x):
    global c
    length = len( df['t_1'][c] )
    c+=1
    for var in range(length):
        outside.append(x)

def get_inside_value(y):
    for var in y:
        inside.append(var[0])
        value.append(var[1])


df['id'].apply(get_outside)
df['t_1'].apply(get_inside_value)

hier_index = list(zip(outside,inside))
hier_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(hier_index)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(value ,index=hier_index,columns=['g',])
new_df.index.names = ['id','f']
new_df
```

*Output*

```
            g
  id    f   
 100    a   1
        b   2
 151    x   4
        y   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nested list comprehension with `zip`:

```
zipped = zip(df['id'], df['t_l'])
df = pd.DataFrame([(i, y1, y2) for i, x in zipped for y1, y2 in x], columns=['id','f','g'])
print (df)
    id  f  g
0  100  a  1
1  100  b  2
2  151  x  4
3  151  y  3
```

If need MultiIndex Series:

```
zipped = zip(df['id'], df['t_l'])
s = pd.Series({(i, y1):y2 for i, x in zipped for y1, y2 in x})
print (s)
100  a    1
     b    2
151  x    4
     y    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','f','g'])
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    x, y = row
    for i in range(len(y)):
        (a,b) = y[i]
        if i==0:
            new.loc[str(ind)] = x,a,b
        else:
            new.loc[str(ind)+str(i)] = '',a,b
```

This will unpack the t_1 elements systematically and output the dataframe in a structure you want.

**Output:**

```
     id  f  g
0   100  a  1
01       b  2
1   151  x  4
11       y  3
```

*Caution: It is a simple approach, however can be significantly more costly if used for large amounts of data.*